# Scheduled task doesn't stop when web server is restarted by dev-tools

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have this problem:

I am scheduling a task to run every 10 minutes. When it runs, I expect to receive two emails from two checks failing.

However, when I edit my project, the dev-tools pick up the changes and restart the spring application. But here is the problem: I still receive emails from the old application running.

What can I do to properly terminate the application? I am afraid that this problem will also affect the production environment.

Code:

```
@Component
public class CheckRunner implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CheckRunner.class);

    private static boolean runOnce = true;

    private final long DEFAULT_CHECKING_INITIAL = 1L;
    private final long DEFAULT_CHECKING_PERIOD = 10L;

    @Autowired
    public EmailServiceImpl emailService;

    /**
     * Construct and schedule a CheckRunner 
     */
    public CheckRunner() {
        if(runOnce) {
            runOnce = false;
            log.info("Starting check runner.");
            ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, DEFAULT_CHECKING_INITIAL , DEFAULT_CHECKING_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run the checks once
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("Checking thread running.");
        checks();
    }

    /**
     * Do the checks
     */
    private void checks() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append("<pre>");
        WebServerAvailablityCheck.runAllChecks(sb, emailService);
        //sb.append("</pre>");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try implementing `Closeable` on your `CheckRunner` bean and call `shutdown` on the executor from within it. Spring will call `Closeable.close()` when the bean is destroyed.

Comment: if you are using spring why don't you use `@Schedule` annotation

Comment: @AndyBrown Do you mean `java.io.Closable` or other interface?

Comment: `Closeable.close` works, thanks

Comment: Yes, `java.io.Closeable`. Spring looks for it and respects it. Glad you've got it working. I'll transpose my comment into an answer so that others may find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement `java.io.Closeable` on your `CheckRunner` bean and call `shutdown()` on the executor from within it then Spring will call `Closeable.close()` when the bean is destroyed. This will cause your executor thread to close gracefully.